# How to pass parameters in action method of apex:page tag

Tags: lightning, action, apexpage

I have overridden the view page of opportunity and based of certain scenarios I am redirecting to different pages.

Initially I have used window.location.href inside outputpanel tag to redirect to different pages like:

`<script>window.location.href="{!$Site.Prefix}{!URLFOR('/'+opportunity.id+'?nooverride=1', opportunity.id, null, true)}"<script>`

As both script and window.location have uncertain behavior in lightning view so I have written extension controller and directly called action method to handle redirection.

But I want to access the opportunity.id parameter in action method of custom controller. Can someone please suggest how to pass dynamic param value - opportunity.id to action method of apex:page tag.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is it an extension controller ?

Comment: Yes, I have create a extension controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a simple extension controller ,

```
public with sharing class OpptControllerExtn {
private final Opportunity opp;

public OpptControllerExtn (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    system.debug(opp.Id);

}
```